# How to count number of rows in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to count the number of unread messages in my DB Table but is proving to be very difficult. I've even read tutorials online but to no avail.

What I'm doing should be simple.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
COUNT NUMBER OF ROWS IN NOTIFICATIONSTABLE 
WHERE USERID = @0 AND MESSAGEWASREAD = FALSE
```

Can somebody please point me in the *right* direction? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

```
@helper RetrievePhotoWithName(int userid) 
{ 
    var database = Database.Open("SC"); 
    var name = database.QuerySingle("select FirstName, LastName, ProfilePicture from UserProfile where UserId = @0", userid); 
    var notifications =  database.Query("SELECT COUNT(*) as 'counter' FROM Notifications WHERE UserID = @0 AND [Read] = @1", userid, false); 

var DisplayName = ""; 
if(notifications["counter"] < 1) 
{ 
    DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + " " + name["LastName"]; 
} 
else 
{ 
    DisplayName = name["FirstName"] + ", you have " + notifications["counter"] + " new messages."; 
} 
<a href="@Href("~/Home")" title="My Account"><img src="@Href("~/Shared/Assets/Images/" + name["ProfilePicture"] + ".png")" id="MiniProfilePicture" />&nbsp;@DisplayName</a> 

database.Close();
```

}

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NotificationsTable WHERE 
 UserID = @UserID AND MessageWasRead = 0;
```

[Sql Count Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

Okay so this is based on what I think should be done.  I don't know the underlying types, so it is going to be my best guess.

```
var notifications =  database.QuerySingle("Select COUNT(*) as NumRecs....");

if((int)notifications["NumRecs"] > 0)) .......
```

I changed the query for notifications to QuerySingle.  You don't need a recordest, you only need a scalar value, so that should (hopefully remove your problem with the implicit conversion in the equals you were having.

I would also check to see if your database object implements IDisposable (place it in a using statement if so) as you are calling close, and this won't actually call close (I know it's not dispose but it might have dispose too) if you encounter and exception before the close function is called.

Comment: I was previously using: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfNotifications FROM Notifications WHERE UserId = @0 AND [Read] = @1", userid, false` however that caused me so much problems I thought I was having a heart attack

Comment: @Kevin, it still won't work. I have updated my question with code and details. I keep getting the following: "Compiler Error Message: CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>' and 'int'" but I try changing var notifications = to int notifications = - but that just creates different problems. I've also read online that Counting rows in WebMastrix SQL is very problematic but the solutions have not worked.

Comment: ok this is a c# problem and not an sql problem.  post your sql code, so i can see what the code looks like.

Comment: You would know this is a C# problem if the other person didn't edit my original question!!! ARGH! I hate that!

Comment: @Kevin - I have posted my full code for this helper, in my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int unreadMessageCount = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Notification WHERE UserId=@0 AND Read=@1",UserId,false).Count();

string displayname = name["FirstName"] + " " + name["LastName"] + unreadMessageCount>0?",you have " + unreadMessageCount :"";
```